# Asymptotic forms of Bessel function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, series-expansion

I want to replace Bessel functions by asymptotic forms, so the question is: can I find the best ones with help of *Mathematica*? And if it's possible, how can I do it?

#### Update

How can I get with `Series` the asymptotic form for the large real arguments? According to wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) it must be:

$\quad \quad J_n(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}  \left(e^{\left|
   \Im(z)\right| } O\left(\frac{1}{\left| z\right|
   }\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}-z-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)\right)$

Moreover, though this equation is true, a better approximations may be available for complex $z$. For example, $J_0(z)$, when z is near the negative real line, is approximated better by

$\quad \quad J_0(z) \sim{\sqrt{\frac{-2}{\pi z }}  \cos \left(z+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}$ than by  $J_0(z) \sim{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z }}  \cos \left(z-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}$.

Instead of something like that, for the input

```
Series[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 100 + 3 I, 1}]
```

I get output of the form

```
SeriesData[x, Complex[100, 3], 
  {BesselJ[0, Complex[100, 3]], -BesselJ[1,Complex[100, 3]]}, 0, 2, 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen `Series[]`?

Comment: Since this is one of the examples in the docs for [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) under *Scope*, I would say this question can be closed.

Comment: @J. M. after your comment I found it under scope, thank you. So, Jens is absolutly right, question can be closed.

Comment: Probably, I jumped to conclusions. One more sub-question arose.

Comment: You might want to try expanding with respect to a `DirectedInfinity[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation for the asymptotic form has a sign error. The correct result is produced by *Mathematica*:

```
Normal@Series[BesselJ[n, z], {z, Infinity, 0}]
```

> $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{z}} \cos
>    \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}-z+\frac{\pi
>    }{4}\right)$$

A version of this with additional corrections is found in the documentation, as I said in the comments. The other result for $z$ near the negative real line is actually just a special case of this, after you correct the sign error. Alternatively, you can do asymptotic expansions in other infinite directions like this:

```
Normal@Series[BesselJ[n, z], {z, DirectedInfinity[1 + I], 0}]
```

> $$i \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{i \pi  n}
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{z}} \cos
>    \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}+z+\frac{\pi
>    }{4}\right)$$